# a question on GNS space

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If a $C^*$ algebra have a faithful tracial state ,we can construct a representation $(\pi_{\tau},H_{\tau})$ of $A$.$H_{\tau}$ can be obtained as following:

Let $N=\{a\in A,\tau(a^*a)=0\}$,then $H_{\tau}$ is the completion of $A/N$.

My question:if $\tau$ is a faithful tracial state,then $N=0$,$A/N=A$.Since $A$ is complete,the completion of $A/N$ is $A$.That is to say,the GNS space is $A$.Is my understanding true?

Comment: Is $A$ necessarily complete with respect to the norm $a\mapsto \sqrt{\tau(a^*a)}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is infinite-dimensional, it will usually not be complete in the $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm. For a trivial example, take $A=L^\infty[0,1]$ and $\tau$ integration against Lebesgue measure. Then $\tau$ is a faithful trace, and $H_\tau=L^2[0,1]$.